# Alternative to Google Appspot

Tags: google-app-engine, vps

I'm in a different country other than US.. but would like to use google appspot.. though i do not have a compatible phone. Is there any alternative that i could install on my own VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use appspot by using a google voice number, or asking someone to do it for you. There is nothing quite like appspot, but it's basically a very broad framework. There are a number of python frameworks, one that comes to mind is django.